# Onsen - adding ons-carousel-items dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, instagram, onsen-ui

I am new in using the Onsen framework and I have been stuck in something.

It is difficult to explain but with the help of some photos I hope I can explain it well.

The issue I have is that I am using ons-carousel with the ons-carousel-items and I am loading the items dynamically into the DOM.

I have been able to make the ons-carousel-item appear into the DOM when the selected page is active, but I can see anything at all.

The current DOM looks like this when it loads the selected page:
[image: First load in the page]

As you can see, the on-carousel-item gets loaded into the page but I cant see anything, I notice after a while searching is that the items are loaded BUT there is inline-style missing..

If I change page the ons-carousel-item gets loaded with the styles that are missing and It works. 
Like this:
[image: When the page is loaded again]

So now it works.. But I dont know what to do to fix it.

In the HTML it looks like this:

```
<ons-tabbar>
  <ons-tab persistent="" page="home.html" active="true" >
    <ons-icon icon="ion-home"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Home</span>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab persistent="" page="home2.html" class="app-instaList-click">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-star"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Favorites</span>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="home3.html">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-gear-a"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Settings</span>
  </ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>

<ons-template persistent="" id="home.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Map</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="home2.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Single List</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div class="content-padded">
      <ons-carousel fullscreen swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll auto-refresh class="insta-list" var="carousel">
      </ons-carousel>
    </div>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

The code looks like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.app-instaList-click', function() {
    var insta = data.data[i];
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 

      ons.ready(function() {
        var instaItem = $(
        '<ons-carousel-item class="insta-item">' +
          '<div class="profile">' +
            '<img src="data.data[i].user.pr"/>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<figure><a href="#">' +
            '<img src="../images/image.jpg"</a></figure>' +               
        '</ons-carousel-item>');

     instaItem.appendTo($('.insta-list'));
     ons.compile(instaItem[0]);
     });
   }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are errors in `<img src="../images/image.jpg"</figure>`. It should be `<img src="../images/image.jpg"></a></figure>`.

Try to use `carousel.refresh()` method: http://onsen.io/reference/ons-carousel.html#method-refresh

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi!
About the errors it was my bad when I was posting the issue here, I took a part of the appending text to shorten it down.

I have tried with the carousel.refresh() and it doesnt help.
The issue is that the carousel-items loads to the onsen-page when the page is loaded, and that is after clicking the menu-item. 
BUT the items loads without the necessery styling to work, until I change page and goes back, then it load with the necessary styling to work. 

I am stuck and dont know what to do.

Thanks!